# Creating project from maven archetype: running mvn archetype:generate only creates an App class

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype, archetypes

I'm trying to create a project in a new directory from an archetype. I've created the archetype, and ran "mvn install" in the project's generated-sources/archetype directory. I then change to a fresh directly and run "mvn archetype:generate". I'm then prompted for groupID, artifactID, etc. I provide them, and the project is created. However, when I open that new project, instead of having all the classes and such from the archetype, it only has a blank App.java class. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which archetype are you using to generate your project?

Comment: I'm using a custom archetype that I created from my own project. I found a possible solution: I can run mvn install archetype:update-local-catalog instead of just mvn install and then my custom archetype is recognized

Answer (score 0):

Running 
    mvn install archetype:update-local-catalog will make the custom archetype available. Then running
    mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog:local 
allowed me to be able to select my custom archetype to create the new project from.

Comment: If you just dit a mvn clean install on your archetype, without update-local-catalog, you could still refer to your archetype on the command line: mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=... -DarchetypeArtifactId=... -DarchetypeVersion=...  without using the catalog.